# Spark Streaming : Reading and writing state info to external database like cassandra

Tags: database, save, state, spark-streaming, checkpoint

Spark Streaming :

When there are code changes to spark streaming app., I have to clean the checkpoint to deploy new changes. Effectively i am loosing the historical state, which is really bad.

Is there a way we can save and rebuild State information from external Database like Cassandra, apart from regular check pointing, spark provides by default?

Can you please point me to some coding examples in this regard.

Comment: I need to maintain the Spark streaming state, so as to process the incoming events in that context. Hence we can't avoid checkpointing. My query is how to save the Spark streaming State RDDs (not the OUTPUT data) into external datastore periodically, lets says every 12 hrs?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using receiver less approach like Kafka direct API,  then you can get the offset for the topic read and store it to Cassandra (or any db). And in your init you have to read the offset from the Cassandra and use it in direct API. By this way you can avoid checkpoint and upgrade your jar easily.

To access offset in dstream , examples can be seen here
[offset reading example](https://github.com/koeninger/kafka-exactly-once/blob/master/index.html)

Comment: I need to maintain the Spark streaming state, so as to process the incoming events in that context. Hence we can't avoid checkpointing. My query is how to save the Spark streaming State RDDs (not the OUTPUT data) into external datastore periodically, lets says every 12 hrs?